# How to replicate next button of key board with our customized button?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview, android-keypad

I am developing an web app. I have made some method of JavaScript which takes the input from edit text when the focus change from the edit text, but user have to click the next button from keyboard.

The requirement is that I have to create a button which has customizations. There for how can I perform the same task as the keyboard next button performs on the click of button. Can any body give me some tutorial? Any kind of help will be appreciable.

[image]

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand. Could you reformulate it using paragraphs, shorter sentences and possibly sample screen shots.

Comment: I have many edit text  in web view and previously created method which give the value of edit text  when the focus changes from the one edit text to another .there for I need to use next like in keyboard with my own button